# Working Biceps and Triceps the next day after Chest and Back

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, muscle-gain, muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery

Majority of the people don't recommend working out biceps and triceps the day after chest and back, the primary reason being that your biceps and triceps get a little bit of burn during the chest and back workout and they may be sore and might not have fully recovered. Ideally, I would insert a leg/shoulder day in between those muscles but my schedule doesn't always guarantee that. My question is: Is it possible that biceps and triceps gets fatigued so much during chest and back that they require more than 24 hours to recover? Is it advisable if I go ahead working these muscles on consecutive days keeping in mind the complexity of my schedule?
PS: I've been gyming since 3 and a half months, I weigh 141 lbs, 5'9 height and lift moderate to heavy weight, in bulking phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that biceps and triceps gets fatigued so much during chest and back that they require more than 24 hours to recover?

Yes, it's quite possible.  This depends partly on your [level of training advancement](https://startingstrength.com/glossary/training-advancement).

> Is it advisable if I go ahead working these muscles on consecutive days keeping in mind the complexity of my schedule?

I don't know, but in order to make progress (that is, gain strength), you must **actually recover**; your schedule must accommodate this.